# Converting a list in a dict to a Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read lines from an HTML input file and prepare Series / DataFrames so I can eventually create graphs. I'm using lxml's objectify to take lines of HTML data and convert them to a list. Whenever I try to take the list data and make a Series or DataFrame, I get a Series (or DataFrame) containing a number of elements equal to the number of items in my list, but the data for the elements is my list itself.

The easiest way I can show my problem is:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify
from pandas import Series
line='<tr class="alt"><td>192.168.1.0</td><td>XXDHCP</td><td>Y</td><td>255</td><td>0</td><td>YYDHCP</td><td>Y</td><td>250</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td><td>505</td><td>505</td><td>0</td><td></td></tr>'
htmldata=(objectify.fromstring(line)).getchildren()
htmlseries=Series(htmldata)
```

htmlseries ends up looking like:

```
0     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
1     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
2     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
3     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
4     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
5     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
6     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
7     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
8     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
9     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
10    [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
11    [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
12    [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
13    [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 255, 0, YYDHCP, Y, ...
```

`type(htmldata[0])` is: `lxml.objectify.StringElement`
`type(htmldata[3])` is: `lxml.objectify.IntElement`

While I'm looking for something like:

```
0     192.168.1.0
1          XXDHCP
2               Y
3             255
4               0
5          YYDHCP
6               Y
7             250
8               0
9              0%
10            505
11            505
12              0
13
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm kind of mystified as to what's going on. When I try reading each column into a list:

```
data=objectify.fromstring(line).getchildren()
labdata[ip]['Scope'].append(data[0])
labdata[ip]['Cluster1'].append(data[1])
labdata[ip]['Active1'].append(data[2])
...etc...
```

My list ends up looking like:

```
labdata['192.168.1.0']['Utilization']
['100%',
 '96%',
 '96%',
 '90%',
 '81%',
 '96%',
 '90%',
 '97%',
 '98%',
 '92%',
 '99%',
 ...etc...
 ]
```

But for some reason:

```
Series(labdata['192.168.1.0']['Utilization'])
0     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 0, 383, YYDHCP, Y...
1     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 28, 355, YYDHCP, ...
2     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 28, 355, YYDHCP, ...
3     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 76, 307, YYDHCP, ...
4     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 104, 279, YYDHCP,...
5     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 27, 356, YYDHCP, ...
6     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 66, 317, YYDHCP, ...
7     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 15, 368, YYDHCP, ...
8     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 15, 368, YYDHCP, ...
9     [[[192.168.1.0, XXDHCP, Y, 54, 329, YYDHCP, ...
...etc...
```

`type(labdata['192.168.1.0']['Utilization'][0])` is `lxml.objectify.StringElement`

Do I need to cast these elements to normal strings and ints?

Comment: make sure that the type of ``labdata['192.168.1.0']['Utilization']`` is actually a ``list``, e.g. put ``list()`` around it, it might be list-like but not actually a list, also show the type of the first element of the series, e.g. ``type(s[0])``

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  The question is comprehensible and provides a working SSCCE, which already ranks it pretty highly.    The only thing missing is a description of the desired output, but in context I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: @dooz: as a workaround you can use `Series(obj.pyval for obj in htmldata)`.  I can't immediately see why, but something about the `lxml.objectify.*Element` objects isn't playing nicely with Series construction.

Comment: Right, my (now deleted) answer was basically DSM's comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the elements in htmldata are not simple types, and np.isscalar is fooled here
(as this is how its determined whether we have list-of-lists or a list of scalars
just stringify the elements are this will work

```
In [23]: print [ type(x) for x in htmldata ]
[<type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.IntElement'>, <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>]

In [24]: Series([ str(x) for x in htmldata ])
Out[24]: 
0     192.168.1.0
1          XXDHCP
2               Y
3             255
4               0
5          YYDHCP
6               Y
7             250
8               0
9              0%
10            505
11            505
12              0
13
```

Comment: Ah, +1.  I remember `isscalar` causing problems with Sage, too -- `numpy` doesn't recognize Sage integers as scalars, so indexing of arrays doesn't work quite right.  I think I prefer the `pyval` approach though as it preserves more type information.

Comment: agreed....not much else I think can do on pandas end because pretty intensive to determine if the user REALLY is passing a list as a series element and means it

Answer (score 2):

Nice question! This is weird behaviour.

The problem occurs because you're passing Series a list `lxml.objectify.StringElement`s. `pandas` is backed by `np.array`s and therefore prefers to have its data stored in uniform arrays. It's therefore abstracting everything into an `np.object` so that it can shove them into an array. Indeed, if you look at the underlying array (`Series.values`) of your data, you'll see that it's been created fine, although it's a numpy array of `lxml.objectify.StringElements` which is probably not what you want.

The easy solution is of course to cast everything to string, which is probably what you want to do in this case.

---

But why is it printing funny, you ask? Well, if you drill through the code in pandas, you end up at the following function in `pandas.core.common`:

```
def _is_sequence(x):
    try:
        iter(x)
        len(x) # it has a length
        return not isinstance(x, basestring) and True
    except Exception:
        return False
```

In other words, pandas sees that the lxml objects are not basestrings, and hence assumes they're sequences. Pandas should probably check `isinstance(x, collections.Sequence)`...